# Compare dateTime to date in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

As said in the title i want to compare dates with laravel.

here's what ive done so far:

```php
if (isset($this->date_filed) && !empty($this->date_filed) && !empty($this->warranty_expiration)) {
    $warranty_expiration = Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $this->warranty_expiration);
    $date_filed = Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $this->date_filed);
    $this->with_warranty = $date_filed->lt($warranty_expiration) ? 'Y' : 'N';
}
```

if date filed is less than Warranty Expiration print Y else N

in my blade file:

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="form-control-label"><b>Within Warranty:</b></label>
     <p>{{$model->with_warranty}}</p>
</div>
```

but i get this error:

> The separation symbol could not be found\r\n
>       Trailing data

what have i done wrong ?

Comment: What is `var_dump($this->date_filed, $this->warranty_expiration);`?

Comment: [date_filed] => 2019-08-28 , [warranty_expiration] => 2019-07-15

Comment: Did the data come out like that, as an array? Then it sounds like you need to use `$this->date_filed['date_filed']`?

Comment: nope. i see that's what im lacking. i will try this thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
$warranty_expiration = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($this->warranty_expiration))
$date_filed = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($this->date_filed))
```

And then use the equal/higher or equal/lower for proper comparison

You can also use the "setAttribute" for adding whatever you want in case of warranty yes/not

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if (isset($this->date_filed) && !empty($this->date_filed) && !empty($this->warranty_expiration)) {
    $warranty_expiration = Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $this->warranty_expiration);
    $date_filed = Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $this->date_filed);
    $this->with_warranty = $date_filed->lt($warranty_expiration) ? 'Y' : 'N';
}
```

To:

```
if (isset($this->date_filed) && !empty($this->date_filed) && !empty($this->warranty_expiration)) {
    $warranty_expiration = Carbon::parse($this->warranty_expiration)->format('m-d-Y');
    $date_filed = Carbon::parse($this->date_filed)->format('m-d-Y');
    $this->with_warranty = $date_filed->lt($warranty_expiration) ? 'Y' : 'N';
}
```

See more: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Do you fix it? @allenconbulan :)